# Inner Function for scipy.integrate.quad's Integrand Parameter Returning NoneType Unexpectedly

Tags: python, scipy, numerical-integration

I am attempting to integrate the following:

[image: $A_0 = \alpha - \frac{1}{\pi} \int_0 ^ c \left[ \frac{2 z'}{c} \cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{1 - \left( \frac{2x}{c} - 1 \right) ^ 2}} \right] dx$]

where
[image: tex $ z' = \begin{Bmatrix} \frac{2m}{p^2} (p - x), & 0 \leq x \leq p\\ \\ \frac{2m}{(1 - p)^2} (p - x), & p < x \leq 1 \end{Bmatrix}$]

As such, I would like to use an inner function for `z_prime` within my code, which is as follows:

```py
import numpy as np
import scipy.integrate as integrate

alpha = np.linspace(-10, 10, 100) # deg
NACA = '2412'
c = 1.2 # m
   
def z_prime(x, naca, c):
   m = float(naca[0]) / 100
   p = float(naca[1]) * c / 10

   if 0 <= x <= p:
      return (2 * m) * (p - x) / (p ** 2)
   if p < x <= 1:
      return (2 * m) * (p - x) / ((1 - p) ** 2)

def integrand_0(x, naca, c):
   return 2 * z_prime(x, naca, c)/ c / np.sqrt(1 - (2 * x / c - 1) ** 2)

for a in alpha:
   A0 = np.deg2rad(a) - integrate.quad(integrand_0, 0, c, args = (NACA, c)) / np.pi
```

Unfortunately, I keep getting the following error:

```
return 2 * z_prime(x, naca, c)/ c / np.sqrt(1 - (2 * x / c - 1) ** 2)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'int' and 'NoneType'
```

I have isolated the issue to be just `2 * z_prime(x, naca, c)` which doesn't make much sense to me.

EDIT:
Changing the inequalities within the `if` expressions above to

```py
if 0 <= x / c <= p:
   return (2 * m) * (p - x) / (p ** 2)
if p < x / c <= 1:
   return (2 * m) * (p - x) / ((1 - p) ** 2)
```

now gives a separate issue:

```
A0 = np.deg2rad(a) - (integrate.quad(integrand_0, 0, c, args = (NACA, c))) / np.pi
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'tuple' and 'float'
```

SOLVED: `scipy.integrand.quad` returns a tuple as shown on https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/tutorial/integrate.html that is `[value, error]`. Using an index `[0]` we can isolate what we need.

Comment: `z_prime` has two `if` expressions, but no `else`.  Thus for some `x` is could 'fall off the end' and return `None`.

Comment: @hpaulj you were correct. Changing the `if` inequalities to  `0 <= x / c <= p` and `p < x / c <= 1`, respectively, solved that issue. I have updated my post with another problem, however.